# ¿Por qué, en C, printf() usa %f para float y double pero scanf() diferencia el uso de ambos con %f y %lf?

Tags: c, double, printf, scanf, float

Cuando se desea imprimir un valor de tipo `float` o `double` usando la función `printf()` se usa el especificador `%f` para ambos tipos de datos. Por ejemplo:

```
double d = 3.5;
float f = 4.5;
printf("Valores: %f %f", f, d);
```

Mientras que en el caso de la función `scanf()`, se usa el especificador `%f` para leer un `float` y el especificador `%lf` para leer un `double`:

```
double d;
float f;
printf("Introduce un float y un double: ");
scanf("%f %lf", &f, &d);
```

**¿Por qué hay especificadores distintos para los tipos `float` y `double` en `scanf()`, pero el mismo especificador en `printf()`?**

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**El lenguaje C realiza una conversión implícita de `float` a `double` cuando se pasa por argumento un valor tipo `float` a una función con número variable de argumentos**, como el caso de la función `printf()`. Por lo tanto, ya sea pasar un valor `float` o pasar un `double`, la función `printf()` recibe un valor `double`, estando establecido el especificador `%f` para imprimir valores tipo `double` en `printf()`

Para el caso de `scanf()` no se pasan por argumentos valores (tipo `float` o `double`) sino que se pasan punteros con las direcciones de memoria donde guardar los valores leídos. Los punteros no son convertidos implícitamente por C, además de que la función `scanf()` debe saber qué tipo de dato es cada una de las variables donde va a guardar cada valor leído, para no ocupar zonas de memoria mayores de las reservadas o no guardar datos con un formato incorrecto a la variable correspondiente. Por lo tanto, es necesario un especificador concreto para cada variable con su tipo de dato correspondiente.

Desde el estándar **C99**, sí está establecido un especificador concreto para cada tipo de dato de punto flotante, tanto para `printf()` como para `scanf()`:

> - `%f` para `float`
> - `%lf` para `double`
> - `%Lf` para `long double`

Al usar la función `printf()` con el especificador `%f` se puede seguir usando sin problemas argumentos de tipo `float` o `double`. Es más, es indiferente usar `%f` o `%lf` con valores tipo `float` o `double`. En todas las posibles combinaciones entre ellos, `printf()` convierte implícitamente a `double` y lo imprime como tal. Pero **usar el especificador `%lf` con valores `float` o `%f` con valores `double` se considera mala práctica** que debe ser evitada, aunque no dé inicialmente problemas.

---

*Para escribir esta solución, en gran parte se ha usado la información de la entrada de SO en inglés: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/210590/why-does-scanf-need-lf-for-doubles-when-printf-is-okay-with-just-f*