# Problemas al calcular promedio para determinar si un alumno ganó un reconocimiento

Tags: c

He tratado de resolver el siguiente problema:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sin embargo, no logro identificar en qué me estoy equivocando. Ya le di muchas vueltas con el `if/else` y realmente no sé cuál es el problema.

Mi código no compila; hasta el momento he intentado hacer lo siguiente

```
#include <stdio.h> 
//CalfT= calificacion final
int main() {
        float calf_1,calf_2,calf_3,calf_4,calf_5,CT;
        
        printf("Dime tu primer calificacion ");
        scanf("%d",&calf_1);
        printf("Dime tu SEGUNDA calificacion ");
        scanf("%d",&calf_2);
        printf("Dime tu tercer calificacion ");
        scanf("%d",&calf_3);
        printf("Dime tu cuarta calificacion ");
        scanf("%d",&calf_4);
        printf("Dime tu quinta calificacion ");
        scanf("%d",&calf_5);
        
        CT=(calf_1+calf_2+calf_3+calf_4+calf_5)/5;
        
        if (CT = 9.5 || CT > 9.5){
                printf(" El alumno recibira el premio por el promedio de %d",CT);
        }
        else {
                printf("El alumno NO recibira el premio por el promedio de %d",CT);
        }   
}
```

Comment: si tu no sabes cuál es el problema nosotros menos. Se te pide que agregues más texto por que lo que das no es suficiente información, por que dices que está mal?, no te da el resultado correcto? te marca error? o que?. Por favor lee [ask]

Comment: Tampoco pongas etiquetas "a lo loco", pon solo las importantes y que tengan relación con tu pregunta, claramente se ve que usas C, por lo que C++ está de más

Comment: Y por cierto, ¿ya has probado con el operador mayor igual `>=`? Eso reduce la necesidad de usar 2 condicones

Comment: Hee... debes usar `%f` y no `%d`

Comment: ya cambie en lugar de %d a %f y tambien a >= pero si sin funcionareditare la publicaion y adjuntaes mas cosas

Comment: @BetaM en cierta parte se podría considerar duplicado de [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/83349/por-qu%c3%a9-en-c-printf-usa-f-para-float-y-double-pero-scanf-diferencia-el-u), esa respuesta explica mejor lo que yo pude haber explicado en una respuesta aquí. Pero si lo crees conveniente podría dar una respuesta

Comment: @FernandoAparicioHernandez bastante raro, lo acabo de probar y funciona bien. Sería mejor si actualizas el código de la pregunta.

Answer (score 3):

Veo tres problemas en tu código.

El primero es que no especificas si estás programando en C o en C++. Son lenguajes diferentes, con características claramente distintas. No todo el código que puedas escribir en C compilará en C++ y viceversa.

El segundo problema es que intentas leer datos de tipo `float` como enteros:

```
scanf("%d",&calf_1);
```

Aunque ambos tipos de datos ,`float` e `int`, ocupen el mismo número de bytes, la forma de codificar los diferentes valores es distinta. No son tipos compatibles a nivel binario. Si quieres leer `float`, lee `float`:

```
scanf("%f",&calf_1);
```

El último error se encuentra en el `if`:

```
if (CT = 9.5 || CT > 9.5){
//     ^ ASIGNACIÓN!!!
```

C y C++ comparten esta característica, la asignación se hace con `=` y la comparación con `==`.

Por otro lado, dado que el premio únicamente se consigue cuando la nota es **superior** a 9.5, la condición esperada es esta:

```
if (CT > 9.5)
```

Bueno, un último error. Al igual que para leer con `scanf` tienes que ser muy riguroso con el formato, al escribir, más de lo mismo:

```
 printf(" El alumno recibira el premio por el promedio de %d",CT);
 //                                                       ~~  ~~
 //                                                      int  float
```

Aquí `printf` va a coger un dato codificado como `float` y lo va a imprimir como si estuviese codificado en formato `int`, lo cual no es buena idea porque, como te he comentado, no son tipos compatibles entre sí (a nivel binario).

```
 printf(" El alumno recibira el premio por el promedio de %f",CT);
```